# html in express route variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'd like to pass a `<br/>` tag or some form of line break into the route from express to jade. For instance:

express

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('homepage', {
    content:'hello<br/>how are you'
  }
});
```

jade

```
p=content
```

but i just get `hello<br/>how are you` in the output rather than

`hello
how are you`

PS I've added `app.locals.pretty = true;` otherwise the html gets omitted completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you use `!=` instead?

```
p!=content
```